# How to use string.include(substring) to test presence

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose there are five words (substring) cat, dog, elephant, tiger, lion and there is a sentence string  -- >  "We have one cat in our home". Now i need to see which of the substring is present in the string.

So how can we use `string.include(substring)` to check if any of the substring in present in string and if true which substring is it.

Comment: There is no React here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the words to find in an array and use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter out the items that aren't included in the string.

```js
const wordsToFind = ['cat', 'dog', 'elephant', 'tiger', 'lion']

const string = "We have one cat in our home";

const includedWords = wordsToFind.filter(e => string.includes(e))
const doesInclude = includedWords.length != 0;

console.log('Does include? ', doesInclude)
console.log('Included words: ', includedWords)
```